# Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Entidade>'

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, spring-tools-suite

Eu estava fazendo um curso de Angular 10 + Spring boot e me deparei com o seguintes erros:

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
> Type 'ArrayBuffer' is missing the following properties from type 'Entidade': id, description, done, createdDate, doneDate.
> Argument of type 'String' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
> 'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'string' when possible.

Esse erro ocorre na classe `corpo.service.ts`.
Classes abaixo:

**corpo.service.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Entidade } from './entidade'

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CorpoService {

    apiURL: String = 'http://localhost:8080/api/entidades';

  constructor(
   private http: HttpClient 
  ) { }

  salvar (Entidade: Entidade) : Observable<Entidade>{
  return  this.http.post<Entidade>(this.apiURL, entidade)
}
}
```

**entidade.ts**

```
export class Entidade {
    id: number;
    description: string;
    done: boolean;
    createdDate: string;
    doneDate: string;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Entidade } from './entidade';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms'
import { CorpoService } from './corpo.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    description : new FormControl('')
  })

  constructor (
    private service: CorpoService
  ){}

  submit(){
    console.log(this.form.value)
    const entidade: Entidade = { ...this.form.value}
    this.service
    .salvar(entidade)
    .subscribe(savedEntidade => console.log(entidade) )
  }
}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: O que seria **entidade** neste trecho: `return  this.http.post<Entidade>(this.apiURL, entidade)`?

Comment: No caso seria ele estaria salvando os atributos da classe entidade.ts

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal já descobri o erro, no caso o erro estava no apiURL: String = 'http://localhost:8080/api/entidades';
eu alterei a String para string e deu certo.